# Common part of two lists

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

- list_1 is generated each time new
- list_2 is unchangeable

In window is printed list_1 in default black colour and i want to make red numbers if they occur in list_2

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label
from random import randint

list_1 = [randint(1, 100) for i in range(12)]
list_2 = [2, 5, 8, 9, 14, 26, 28, 34, 43, 51, 55, 60, 77]

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text=list_1, padx=15, pady=15)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I've tried like this:

```
if list_2 in list_1:
    label.config(fg='red')
```

or this:

```
for i in list_2:
    for i in list_1:
        label.config(fg='red')
```

But nothing works. Where is mistake?

Comment: Do you want the **entire label** to be red if **any** number is in the other list?

Answer (score 0):

To check for common hashable items in lists you may want to use sets:

```
if set(list_2) & set(list_1):
    label.config(fg='red')
```

Or

```
if any(n in set(list_2) for n in list_1):
    label.config(fg='red')
```

You can also use `any` and a generator expression:

```
if any(n in list_2 for n in list_1):
    label.config(fg='red')
```

But its slower and less pythonic.

Comment: Tried your suggestions but it isnt what i need because this code changes all numbers to red. I want to somethig like this: black(not in list_2) red(in list_2).
list_1 = black(3),black(7),red(14),black(15),red(26),red(28),black(31)        hope you understand what i mean

Comment: To do what you want you need to either group the blacks and the reds into two labels, create a labe for each number, or embed the color to the label content. I'd suggest grouping which is probably easiest (and use two labels).

Comment: I think i know where exactly i made mistake. Label widget can only have one foreground colour. Thats why above code coloured all numbers. In this case i should change to Text widget